# Is it possible to create a custom Gauge chart in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, dashboard, charts

Is it possible to create a custom Gauge chart in LWC?

I have a requirement of creating a gauge chart on dashboard. Target value is sum of one column of report and measure is sum of other column of the report.

I am not able to do it using Dynamic Gauge as the target value is not being stored in a record or field. Hence, I tried to check if I can create a custom LWC component for Gauge chart but can't find any solution as of now.

Thank you

Comment: Your best bet may be to use thirdparty library with custom LWC component. Have you seen this? https://salesforcelabs.github.io/LightningWebChartJS/docs/general/samples.html